# Haml formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm new to haml, so I'm still trying to figure out the formatting.

I have an index.haml file with the following code.

```
%h1
  Welcome to Solidarity

Hello,
= @profile.first_name
!
```

It renders like this:

> Welcome to Solidarity
> Hello, user !

Here's the page source:

```
<h1>
  Welcome to Solidarity
</h1>
Hello,
frances
!
```

It has a space between @profile.first_name and the exclamation mark. Why is that? And, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
%h1 Welcome to Solidarity
Hello, #{@profile.first_name}!
Please #{link_to 'post a comment', new_comment_path}!
```

becomes

```
<h1>Welcome to Solidarity</h1>
Hello, John!
Please <a href="/comments/new">post a comment</a>!
```

Please keep in mind that in Rails 2 and Haml 2, you must properly html-escape anything you send to the browser (ht nex3):

```
Hello, #{h @profile.first_name}!
```

In Rails 3 and Haml 3, everything is escaped by default, so you can simply do:

```
Hello, #{@profile.first_name}!
```

Comment: Thanks!

Also, similarly, link_to calls have the extra space at the end. How should those be resolved?

Comment: Edited my answer to add an example of `link_to`.

Comment: Don't forget to HTML-escape the username!

Comment: Thanks nex3. I edited my answer to include escaping in Rails 2.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use "alligators" to "eat" the white space before or after a tag. From the [haml-lang docs](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_):

```
%img
%pre><
  foo
  bar
%img
```

is compiled to:

```
<img /><pre>foo
bar</pre><img />
```

While this would have also solved your problem here, the solution given by Justice is the appropriate markup for this scenario. Just thought I'd mention it.